# react native intercom couldn't load your conversation

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, intercom

Intercom message couldn't open sometimes on production mode.(iOS)
It works fine in debug mode.
There is no error or warning on console.
Did anyone face this issue?

[image: iPhone screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
You need to check if your API key is setup on `Settings` > `Installation` > `iOS`

https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/ios-installation#section-step-3-initialize-intercom